# How to filter a CSV file based on a String array value

Tags: arrays, string, scala, apache-spark, filtering

I am using Spark Scala and I created a String array from a CSV column and I want to use the array values to filter another CSV file. I am trying with this code :

```
val ID_a = dTestSample1.select("ID").dropDuplicates("ID")
val x =ID_a.select("ID").collect().map { row => row.toString() }
var i = 0 
for (newID <- x){
  val sbinPercent5 = dTestSample1.filter("ID".equals(newID )) ...................................
  i+=1 }
```

I am getting "overloaded method value filter" error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
ID_a.select("ID").collect()
```

This piece of code returns an `Array`, that you then turn into an `Array[String]` by applying the `row => row.toString()` function with `map`. However, at this point, you no longer have a `DataFrame`.

`Array`s have an implicit conversion that allow you to use methods like `filter` on it. `filter` is a *higher order function* that takes a predicate, in your case a function like the following `String => Boolean`. However, instead of passing a function that takes a `String` and returns a `Boolean`, you are directly calling the method `equals` on the string `"ID"`, so you are passing the `filter` a `Boolean` instead of a predicate.

It looks like you are trying to use the DataFrame API to an `Array`, however what you can do to solve the problem is just pass a predicate to the `filter` method:

```
 dTestSample1.filter(s => s.equals(newID))
```

or more consisely

```
 dTestSample1.filter(_.equals(newID))
```

My suggestion is, however, to try to fully leverage the DataFrame API for the query you are doing, which apparently is counting the number of occurrences of a given value in the `ID` column of your initial `DataFrame` and that can be pretty simply expressed as follows:

```
val df = dTestSample1.select("ID").groupBy("ID").count()
```

You can now `collect`, `show` or perform any sort of action with a `DataFrame` that holds the count of occurrences of each value of the `ID` column.